# I entered some "dbus remove" command(or something like it) but now laptop is an inexpensive paperweight

Tags: linux, chrome

Okay so I'm going to pass on the whole add a picture thing because I think it's easy to see it. Chromebook 3... blue light on side turns on... nothing happens internally... black screen. No boot screen, not a thing, nothing. I'm very sorry I dont have more on the exact command I entered to render this a pile of unbootable metal and plastic but someone please!!! please remove this from my reality. Someone, tell me, how it is possible to regain access to the device. I dont necessarily need to retain information on the device. It can be lost and inrecoverable but someone help. I was in the developer mode of the laptop so I'm pretty sure what I did was kinda damaging but it can't be just irreparable. There has to be a way to mount, or reboot, of some kind or of that same essence to regain the laptop. Someone, please empart wisdom. This is beyond my capabilities and it has happened around a week ago and as time continues I lose sight of what happened in memory

Comment: So you were in the BIOS?

Comment: I had entered into developer mode, yes. [CTRL + ALT + F2/(forward)] so no I had not been tooling around in the linux container that you can activate from the settings menu.

Answer (score 0):

You’ll need to boot your Chromebook into Recovery Mode. Press and hold down the Esc and Refresh keys and then tap the Power button. (The Refresh Key is where the F3 key would be — the fourth key from the left on the top row of the keyboard.) From there you will need to find other forums and information on undoing what you did.

Comment: I believe that i have actually, in some form/fashion, accidentally found a way to _format_ the boot sequence. If you'll excuse the android reference as it shouldn't be applied for this but it explains the dilemma in the fullest sense. I wonder if that is factually possible; to inadvertently erase the system calls that take place during start up and if so would I have to reset the "road" it takes to bring up login screen.. As you said, forums here I come. Yayy. At any rate, thanks for your help